# Sandisk USB thumb drive won't mount because file system is not Installed

Tags: mount, usb-drive, disk-utility

my not working flash SANDISK 8GB 
im use disk untility for formating not working usb busy and unmount or mount not working?

help any and terminal im use

Comment: Let's look at this video http://youtu.be/rwK_sfui5mw  my problem

Comment: did u try after rebooting? try command `udisks --unmount /dev/sdb1` ? does it mount in other systems?

Comment: Yes, I have tried everything  but does not work

Comment: windows working flash but ubuntu not

Comment: not working sudo umount

Comment: Check if the USB drive is formatted exFat.

Answer (score 1):

Looking more closely to your video seems that the File System is unknown to Ubuntu or that you don't have a partition table. To fix this, you should save all your data (since you say that Windows still recognize that mess) then go to the Disk Utils, and click "Format Drive", then select FAT32 from the options and *Voila* your driver works in Ubuntu and Windows.